# Не могу отправить электронное письмо

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина! С помощью заполнения Электронной формы пытаюсь отправить письмо. Но почему php не хочет отправлять. Может у вас получиться найти ошибку...

php:

```
<?php

 // Определение некоторых констант
 define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );

 define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "Avtoclub-MIR@art.ru" );

 define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

// Чтение формы

$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";

$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";

$phone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_match( '/^\d{10}$/', '', $_POST['phone'] ) : "";

$marka = isset( $_POST['marka'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $_POST['marka'] ) : "";

$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

 //Если  все значения в норме, отправляем по электронной почте
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $phone && $marka && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";

$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . "<" . $phone . ">" . $marka . ">";

$success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

 // Вернуться соответствующий ответ браузеру
if 
( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} 
else {
?>
```

<html>

<head>

<title>Thanks!</title>

```
</head>

<body>

<?php if ( $success ) 
echo "<p>Спасибо за отправкой сообщения! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.</p>" 
?>

 <?php 
 if ( !$success ) echo "<p>Существует проблема отправке сообщения. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.</p>" 
?>

<p>Нажмите кнопку Назад в браузере, чтобы вернуться к странице.</p>
```

</body>

```
</html>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: @Arty21, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 

#**{}** 

редактора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в один из самых нервных языков на планете!

Код

```
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $phone && $marka && $message )
```

не выполнится, если хотя бы в одной из переменных содержится пустая строка.
Лично я часто специально привожу переменные к типам в коде, хоть это и выглядит как из пушки по воробьям (здесь приведение не нужно, я про ситуацию в целом). С вашей стороны я бы разделил валидацию и данные (вы проверяете валидность формы наличием самих данных, в то время как пустые строки не запрещены).

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

> var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)